# Best way to dynamically change the resolution of an HTML5 video

Tags: css, dynamic, resize, html5-video

What is the best way to dynamically change the width and height of an HTML5 video within a webpage? The kind of behaviour I'm referring to is the same thing in the intro video of http://flipboard.com/

When the window is resized, the video still takes up 100% of the viewable size (without scrolling). I noticed that the video gets resized to a certain degree, but stops resizing and gets cropped at some point.

What is the best way to get the same behaviour? I want to have a video take up the entire viewable area of the browser without scroll bars. This is only on a desktop/laptop, I am not considering any mobile devices ATM.

What I have in mind right now is to dynamically change the width/height properties of the video to fit the viewable area using javascript, but also set a minimum size such that the video doesn't get distorted. The video can be placed in a container that is always centered, so if the browser gets to a size that is too small, it effectively gets cropped. I'm not sure if this is too long-winded and if there is an easier way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they have the css properties of height and width set to 100%.  If you use an element inspector like the one built into chrome or firebug for Firefox, you should be able to see exactly how they structured the html/css for the `video` element as well as the `div` its nested in.  Then, as you said, also set a min-width/min-height property.

Unless I'm misreading your question, it should be that simple.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you could do it with "Responsive CSS", there are some ways to do that, 
 
you could set the `viewport`, `max-width`, `min-width`, etc.
This link have a nice explanation how to do that : http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/responsive-layouts-using-css-media-queries/